# Should I use systemd or docker-compose to keep Docker containers running on my systems?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, systemd

We are talking about Docker containers as sysdig, consul, fluentd, mesos-slave, etc. that we are running on almost all machines.

Currently we are using Ubuntu's Upstart and CoreOS's Fleetctl. We're migrating to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and currently considering whether to convert the configuration to:

- Systemd or
- Docker-compose

Systemd can do health checks and automatically bring back processes that died back online. It's also the most similar to Upstart that we use heavily. Our Upstart configuration files are generated from cloud-config like this:

```
- >
    /usr/local/bin/generate-docker-upstart fluentd registry/fluentd:1.0.1
    -e HOST=elasticsearch
    -e PORT=9200
    -e INDEX=fluentd
    -e NODE=`hostname -s`
    -e ROLE=app
    -e ENVIRONMENT={{Ref:Environment}}
    -e TENANT={{Ref:Tenant}}
    -p 24224:24224
    --name \$NAME \$IMAGE
```

We use AWS CloudFormation to bring the virtual machines online.

We cannot use a real container orchestration framework (we already use Marathon/Mesos) because these services have to be running on each host and before Marathon/Mesos run.

What solution makes most sense? Convert these files to systemd or start using docker-compose, despite already using Marathon on Mesos?

Comment: Tool recommendation requests are explicitly off-topic here, per #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Either of these approaches *can* be made to work. Which one you *should* use is going to come down to the individual opinions of those answering questions. (There are some extra tools required to wrap a Docker instance in systemd without unwanted side effects caused by interactions between how docker and systemd handle cgroups, but those tools work pretty well).

Answer (score 4):

The restart policy is built-in method to keep Docker containers running.

`docker run --restart=always -d image_name`

see the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart) for details

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer:* I am not a systemd-savvy user, so my answer will amount to summarize some features of docker-compose and give a few pointers.

You said

> We cannot use a real container orchestration framework […] What solution makes most sense? Convert these files to systemd or start using docker-compose, despite already using Marathon on Mesos?

but it can be noted that `docker-compose` is itself a containers orchestration tool (albeit more lightweight than some other orchestration solutions).

> Systemd can do health checks and automatically bring back processes that died back online. It's also the most similar to Upstart that we use heavily. Our Upstart configuration files are generated from cloud-config like this: […]

You may already have some insights on `docker-compose`, but just to summarize for completeness, it may be viewed as a "Docker frontend", implemented in Python, that allows one to:

1. replace complex Docker commands (such as `docker build`, `docker run`, etc.) with declarative configurations in YAML. See [the doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) for more details on this expressive specification.
2. manage the whole life cycle of multi-containers applications (possibly using custom networks, volumes, and so on). In particular, it is possible to tell `docker-compose` to always restart a given container in case of error, and to [specify health checks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck).
   For example, see the following two pointers:

   - https://blog.codeship.com/ensuring-containers-are-always-running-with-dockers-restart-policy/ (personally I tend to prefer the `restart: unless-stopped` policy)
   - https://howchoo.com/g/zwjhogrkywe/how-to-add-a-health-check-to-your-docker-container (with a Python web app example involving a container health check).

Finally, note that using `docker swarm` may be another alternative solution, that is as least as "standard" as `docker-compose`, and which additionally has a clustering feature − to turn a group of Docker engines into a single virtual Docker engine ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)#Tools)).

Two related pointers:

- https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2017/08/15/docker-features-for-handling-containers-death-and-resurrection/ (mentions a Python program that handles signals, container health check, and `docker swarm`)
- https://www.linux.com/news/8-open-source-CONTAINER-ORCHESTRATION-TOOLS-KNOW